# Weblogic blocks Rest Post call by asking for authentication

Tags: weblogic11g

I am trying to post a file to a URL programmatically. This URL is protected by its own username/password. 
I have inherited this URL (or application) - so it is in my ownership. It is basically a web application used to host some files.

I have created an HttpClient which takes HttpPost consisting of the URL and file to be uploaded.

```
  this.httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
this.httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(this.host, this.port), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(this.username, this.password)); 

  HttpResponse response = this.httpClient.execute(httpPost, this.context);
  HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

  log("Received HTTP response: " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase(), LogLevel.INFO.getLevel());
```

But somehow weblogic authentication blocks it and I receive "Unauthorized" response. If I use the username/password of weblogic admin console, then authentication is fine but fails while uploading since the URL is protected by a different credential(Same as the one I am trying to upload with).

Any idea what am I doing worng? Why weblogic is asking for its own authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue. I needed to set enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials equal to false in domain config.xml . This bypasses weblogic authentication and the application authentication kicks in.